# matrix with chosen elements distributed in a random position

Tags: matrix, random

I would like to generate a matrix whose dimension is L^2 and whose entries can be only in a finite set but in random positions in the matrix.

such as

```
 M[b_]:=RandomReals[{0,b},{L,L}]
```

where b is an integer. However the latter gives random values in the range 0 to b, while I want only entries that can be only 0 or b....namely several b distributed randomly in the matrix and all the other elements 0.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice.html),

```
RandomChoice[{0, b}, {4, 3}]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0}, {b, b, 0}, {0, 0, b}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

For the case with two elements `0` and `b` you can also use:

```
b RandomInteger[1, {4, 4}]
```

> {{0, 0, b, 0}, {0, 0, b, b}, {b, b, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0, 0}}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Galuoises, my pleasure.